# Mixing two audio in Windows Media Foundation

Tags: audio, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to mix two audio in Windows media foundation. In MATLAB I did it adding sample by sample from each audio. In windows media foundation I can access the samples using `IMFSourceReader` and `IMFSample` which gives me a chunk of data for some duration. For example first call to `sourceReader->ReadSample(`) gives me first `t` duration of data. next call to it gives me next `t` turation of data. Each t duration of data lies in buffer size of `L`.

When I tried to access the audio samples using media foundation this way I expected that the duration `t` and buffer length `L` would be same each time I call `ReadSample()`. But I get different t and L each time I call `ReadSample()` for the audios. For example some times I get buffer length 16384, duration 928798 (in 100 nanosecond unit) and sometimes I get buffer length 8192 with duration 464399.

This is a huge problem for me as I cannot add two audio with different buffer length and duration. Is it possible to get fixed size buffer and fixed duration of IMFSamples? If not how can I mix two audio in media foundation?

I first transcoded the audio files to 44100 Hz sampling rate wma file.Then for reading audio I am using this code.

```
CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&spMFTypeIn));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, BITS_PER_SAMPLE));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 44100));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX, 1));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, 16 / 8 * 2));
CHECK_HR(spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, 16 / 8 * 2 * 44100));
```